# How to avoid warning message in Windows AWS CLI S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-cli

We got warning message when S3 upload below. It's not harmful at all, but we'd like surpress if possible.

-- Warning Message

```
C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\.\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1175: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
```

-- Actual Case

```
   c:\temp>aws s3 ls s3://s3-dwh-XXXXX/s3-dwh-backup-exp/
    C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\.\dateutil\parser\_parser.py:1175: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
    2018-11-01 10:10:49          0
    2018-11-01 10:06:53  132872957 DL_CustMstNEW_01.gz
    2018-11-01 10:06:58   41152747 DL_CustMstNEW_02.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:04   43736036 DL_CustMstNEW_03.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:07   42409294 DL_CustMstNEW_04.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:11   39195854 DL_CustMstNEW_05.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:15   37022918 DL_CustMstNEW_06.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:19   40475266 DL_CustMstNEW_07.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:23   40827113 DL_CustMstNEW_08.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:27   40064518 DL_CustMstNEW_09.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:31   40103445 DL_CustMstNEW_10.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:36   38343333 DL_CustMstNEW_11.gz
    2018-11-01 10:07:40   38345654 DL_CustMstNEW_12.gz

    c:\temp>aws s3 ls s3://s3-dwh-XXXXX/s3-dwh-backup-exp/
```

| find /c /v ""
        C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI.\dateutil\parser_parser.py:1175: UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
        13

Maybe we have any encode or module issues, here is our AWS CLI version.

```
c:\temp>aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.10 Python/2.7.9 Windows/2012Server botocore/1.12.0
```

If you know any solutions, please let me know.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This case, you can set variable in powershell

```
Set-Item env:tz -Value your-timezone
```

exemple

```
Set-Item env:tz -Value UTC+1
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow @Guilhermearv, please include the code that you are giving explanation in support of your answer.

Comment: Many, many thanks, @Guilhermearv !! So sorry for my late reply since I didn't notice your comment until now. I tried UTC+9 and confirmed the warning message can be avoid as expected, thank you so much !!